# rails view not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have started with my first rails project using Redmine. I have started to dig into the code to get a better idea and having a hard time understanding the erb files. When I go to make a simple change to the welcome.html.erb file, I make the change and check in the browser and there is no change. Once I save a file is there something that I need to run before the view will be updated? I did not think so, but that is why I am here asking because the view will not update the page when I save the file.

Thank you in advance for any help.

UPDATE: After I update the .html.erb file and open it up again in vim, my changes are still there. Only problem is that the page does not reflect what the change has been made to and when I view source it is not there either?????

Comment: Did you reload the page in the browser?

Comment: Yes I did. I was checking to see if there needed to be a flag just like there is for scss or coffee but I did not find one so I did not know if there was something that I needed to do to watch for changes in a erb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though my cloud server is slow to update the pages so I need to check and see why this is. There is no problem with the pages when working locally and the page was updated in the source the next morning.

Answer (score 0):

Using an IDE is not a good idea when you're learning Rails.
Try opening a console and cd into your application directory. Then run `rails s` and you should see your application running on a browser when you point to `localhost:3000`

You can leave the server running and modify your view file with any text editor. Changes should reflect automatically without even need to restart the server.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you. It is nice to know that nothing has to be done after saving a file. My only problem is that I am working from the terminal on a remote server and when I update the welcome.html.erb file in vim, I go back to the page and there is not update. I will check more into this and see if I am updating the right file. All of the html looks just like it does in chrome developer, just without my updates.